# How do I delete all files within subdirectories matching a given wildcard in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards

I would like to delete all files on a Windows server matching this wildcard:

```
E:\Cache\*\*\*_ROOT\a*_SYMBOL\weekly*
```

In linux, I could just put an `rm -rf` in front of it and it would work.  If I try something similar in Windows, it just gives me:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any ideas about what I can do?

Comment: I believe a batch file with FOR loops will be needed, not any one single command will work.  I needed to write one to delete every subdirectory in a directory.  You batch file would be similar but you would need to test for the name of the directories and travel down each subdirectory.  For a while I did look for a third party RD command to accept wild cards but if we quicker for me to write my own.  However, my situation was simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Power Shell**, which comes built-in in Win7

for example, rm -rf would translate to:

```
Remove-Item E:\Cache\*\*\*_ROOT\a*_SYMBOL\weekly* -force
```

Comment: It's Windows 2008 Server, but that includes PowerShell.  Isn't that handy?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if I want to delete all folders with a certain name anywhere in the sub-tree, but starting at a certain root folder. E.g. delete all folders named `TestResult` within `C:\Projects\` and all subdirectories?

Found the answer - example 4 of the `Remove-Item` command explains it: `get-childitem C:\Projects\* -include TestResults -recurse | remove-item`

Answer (score 0):

Share the folder.  Connect to the share with linux.  Use `ls` to generate a list of files.  Open up your favorite text editor and edit the list.  Add `del` to the front of each line.  Replace all `/` with `\` and change the path from `/cache` to `E:\` .  Add quotes around each path to protect against the `^` in the filename and change all `%` into `%%`.  Copy the contents into a `.bat` file and execute.

Answer (score 0):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is very useful for things like this, if you don't have a linux machine to share to.
After you install it, you'll be able to execute the linux command directly on your windows folders.